# SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR(occurs even converting the source and destination datatypes)

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I faced this error before in the code and one of the expert suggested me a good solution of implicitly converting the datatypes using the advanced editor option.

But the same error occurs even after converting the source and the destination data types to varchar and when i match them in the lookup shape its not retrieving the matching records and is throwing the error.

Is there any solution for this error?

Comment: Go to Advanced Editor for OLE DB Source by right clicking on 'OLE DB Source' / 'Show Advanced Editor...'. Go to the tab 'Input and Output Properties' and expand the option 'OLE DB Source Output' then expand 'Output Columns'. Find your field that is mentioned in the error message and click on it. On the right hand side 'Common Properties' show, find Data Type Properties / Data Type and Length there. Change the data type to what needs to be for that field. That worked fine in my case, I hope it helps you too.

Comment: i tried the above steps too but still throwing an error.

Comment: This error occurs when i try to match values with the lookup table in the lookup shapes...

Comment: I tried using the query as well as the table to match these records in the lookup shape but still I;m getting the error

Comment: Are you matching the datatypes in the Lookup query?

Comment: Yes I'm matching the data types in the lookup qyery as well as checked the data types in the OLEDB source too...

Comment: Tried every means and still the error exsist.. Can anyone give some suggestion plz..

Comment: I am out of guesses, without being able to see your package.